# How to identify risks in a given case study?

Tags: risk-management, risk, business-case

I am working on a case study which is like below :

Economic inequality is a huge issue. A recent study found that the world's 80 wealthiest individuals own as much as the entire world's poorest 3.5 billion people. The richest 1 percent of the world's population control half of the world's total wealth.15 Many individuals, corporations, charities, and government agencies have projects and programs in place to attempt to tackle this and other important global issues such as sustainability, but there are many opportunities to do more.

A trinidad group of college students has decided to work together to do their part in making the world a better place. The students are from many different countries, and several of them met at global conferences, through study abroad experiences, or on various Internet groups. Strategic goals of this group include developing skills for both college students and for needy populations, sharing information on existing products and services that promote economic growth and sustainability, and promoting entrepreneurship. Leaders of this group were reviewing some ideas for projects (all with a significant IT component) that they could do to support their strategic goals:

XYZ: Many people are familiar with the television show called Shark Tank where entrepreneurs (sometimes called “treps”) present their business ideas to a group of investors or sharks. Several colleges, high schools, and even elementary schools throughout the world hold unique versions of a shark tank like event. You believe that creating a nonprofit organization with one central mobile-friendly website/application to assist groups in organizing these types of events would spark even more entrepreneurs throughout the world. You would plan to hold several shark tank like events during the term of the project and create a site and applications to help continue developing more XYZ. This site/application would include the following capabilities:

• Provide guidelines and templates for running a shark tank type of event.

• Accept donations from potential investors targeted toward specific schools or organizations wishing to host an event.

• Accept ideas for needed new products or services.

• Provide the ability for organizations to create their own custom site to solicit local participants and sharks, accept applications, and promote the winners as well as losers.

• Research ideas for a mechanism where a certain percentage of all donations and profits earned by contestants are donated back to the XYZ organization.

• Provide an online version of the events by showing videos of contestants and live reactions of the sharks while also getting live inputs and donations from viewers.

Now I am trying to create **risk register** based on above case study as shown below with columns : [image]

But I am not able to identify the risk in above case study and do we define only those risks that are going to happen after the project is implemented?

Can someone give me 4 to 5 examples of risk please so that I can understand the concept of risk register?

Comment: You’re conflating *project risk* with *business risk.* Don’t do that! Furthermore, I’m not convinced you’re describing a project (e.g. a finite business initiative) within the project management domain. Without editing, this question is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This question also *appears* to be a school assignment. While that doesn’t make it inherently off topic, determining what your teacher expects the “correct” answer(s) to be is a question for them, not strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs There is no right or wrong answer to this type of questions and there is no specific expectations related to this questions as well.Risk is risk in school as well as in business so please stop putting my question as off topic or something else because I am here to learn something and if this is gonna happen everytime than may be its time to leave this site :)

Comment: Questions “with no right or wrong answer” are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A format. Discussions, opinion polls, or other list-generating questions are [explicitly off topic](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) per our help center. There are certainly other forums for such questions if you don’t find our community’s guidelines and policies to your liking, but I hope you’ll choose to participate constructively per our published documentation.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs If according to you this is off-topic than why my question got 2 upvotes? Project management is the subject which I believe always have no right or wrong answers and the topics are always subject to discussions and opinions based on what I have studied so far but anyways since anyone can do anything on SO, I know this is bound to happen :)

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. "But I am not able to identify the risk in above case study"

Some potential risks:

- Not enough people are interested
- The wrong type of people join; not experienced/rich/influential enough
- People make promises and don't keep them, or sign up and don't turn up
- People join for the wrong reasons, e.g. to make a profit for their own business
- Projects cost way more to implement than projected
- Local rules and regulations inhibit timely implementation
- Local customs and culture prevent proper implementation.

#### 2. "and do we define only those risks that are going to happen after the project is implemented?"

I would record those risks that prevent the project from starting and from completing, but not those that are going to happen after the project is fully implemented.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping and for your valuable answer, What could be the positive risks in this ?